# Изменение спрайта и анимации в зависимости от положения курсора 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хочу сделать управление персонажем как в Enter the Gungeon. То есть герой имеет 8 спрайтов (в 8 направлений) и анимации хотьбы + стойки и меняется это в зависимости от положения курсора на экране. Мне удалось сделать такое НО только когда я нажимаю клавиши. Буду благодарен если подскажите как можно добавить в данный код (или изменить его совсем) добавить мышь.
 Чтобы при нажатии клавиш происходило только перемещение по миру, а анимация и спрайты менялись в зависимости от положения курсора. Знания в C# малы, а идею реализовать охото. Буду очень благодарен!
(На гифке показан пример)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 3f;

    Animator thisAnim;
    float lastx, lasty;




    void Start()
    {
        thisAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }


    void Update()
    {
        Move();
    }


    void Move()
    {
        Vector3 rightMovement = Vector3.right * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        Vector3 upMovement = Vector3.up * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        Vector3 heading = Vector3.Normalize(rightMovement + upMovement);


        transform.position += rightMovement;
        transform.position += upMovement;

        UpdateAnimation(heading);
    }

    void UpdateAnimation(Vector3 dir)
    {

        if (dir.x == 0f && dir.y == 0f)
        {
            thisAnim.SetFloat("LastDirX", lastx);
            thisAnim.SetFloat("LastDirY", lasty);
            thisAnim.SetBool("Movement", false);
        }
        else
        {
            lastx = dir.x;
            lasty = dir.y;
            thisAnim.SetBool("Movement", true);
        }

        thisAnim.SetFloat("DirX", dir.x);
        thisAnim.SetFloat("DirY", dir.y);

    }


}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

**Метод 1**

1.2 переменные для координат игрока и курсора (типа vector3)

2.будем отталкиваться от координат игрока,их возьмем за начало координат (0;0)

3.в мировых координатах,естественно,игрок не будет постоянно в точке отсчета,поэтому применим разницу векторов из позиции курсора вычитаем позицию игрока

что-то типа: если позиция курсора (2;2) а игрока (1;0) то для нас позиция курсора будет (1;2)

https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/UnderstandingVectorArithmetic.html

4.с помощью switch,в зависимости от позиции курсора относительно игрока,менять анимацию и сторону движения игрока (представьте круг вокруг игрока или лучше нарисуйте и разбейте на 8 частей,каждая из частей круга будет лежать в какой-то области, **например** : 1 часть от (0;100) до (50;50) и тд)

Ps это скорее велосипед,попытался набросать

**Метод 2**

Векторное произведение

http://www.webmath.ru/poleznoe/formules_13_9.php

Ps нужны некоторые знания математики